# Trying to install a Magento Module that seems to not be Compiler Compatible - Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, mage

trying for some time how to install magento extension on magento 1.7.0.2

Cash On Delivery by mage specialist - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cash-on-delivery-6259.html

tried

three steps 
1) disable cache and compliation , install the extension and reenable the cache and compilation 
2) disable compliation and cache , install the extension and enable the compilation and cache

getting errors : Fatal error: Class ‘MSP_CashOnDelivery_Helper_Data’ not found in /home/bwcom/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

please advise what steps should i follow

Answer (score 2):

**Proper Steps to Install a Module when the compiler has been activated and turned on.**

[Disable the compiler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/358231/), disable the Magento cache and manually clear cache by deleting all `mage--?` subfolders in `var/cache/`

Install the module and log into the Magento admin panel so the installers run. Log back out and then back in to fully load admin code, adminhtml blocks and adminhtml skin files.

Test module operation on backend and frontend and **run website without compilation** until you're satisfied that the module is fully functional.

Enable all the Magento caching you were using before you installed the module and test website function.

Take a sledge hammer and smack the top of your foot so you have a pain reference for what follows.

Go into the `System Tools -> Compiler` page and do a code recompile. This empties and recreates the compiled code base. If you do not do this, you loose your website to a mishmash of old and new code.

Only after a successful recompile do you **attempt** to enable compilation. You probably will loose your website to a module that's not been made fully compatible with the Magento <strike>kludge</strike> compiler... [Disable the compiler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/358231/) and your website should be operational again. You may have to do another Magento cache clear.

**Contact your third party module developer** and see if they intend for it to work under Magento's <strike>kludge</strike> compiler...

For the most part, under Magento 1.7.x.x and 1.8.x.x, there has been a lot of code rewrite that makes the compiler a lot less performance enhancing that it used to be when it was introduced for 1.4.x.x and there are other methods that will cause you less frustration and more performance gain out there. If it's a tossup between a useful module and a useless compiler, the module is more important.

---

**Manually disabling the compiler when a module install has you backed into a corner**

To manually disable the compiler...

1)  find `includes/config.php` and comment the two following lines by putting a # at the beginning of the line like so:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

2) go to `includes/src` and delete all the contents

3) go to `var/session` and delete all the session files

4) go to `var/cache` and delete all the `mage--?` folders

or to use the script in `shell/`, go to shell folder and execute at the command line:

```
php -f compiler.php -- clear
```

and then delete session files and cache folders as in steps 3 and 4 above

The compiler should now be completely disabled and you should be able to start up your Magento installation.