# Magento site crashed after enable compilation

Tags: php, mysql, magento, e-commerce, web-deployment

Hey my Magento site crash after I enable compilation, I cant login to the site, so I am trying to disable it from the back end (config.php) but its disable

```
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

any ideas?
Following are the error codes

```
Warning: include_once(/home3/webcapt/public_html/campusclub/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/webcapt/public_html/campusclub/app/Mage.php on line 36
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home3/webcapt/public_html/campusclub/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home3/webcapt/public_html/campusclub/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php') in /home3/webcapt/public_html/campusclub/app/Mage.php on line 36
Warning: include_once(/home3/webcapt/public_html/campusclub/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/webcapt/public_html/campusclub/app/Mage.php on line 37
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home3/webcapt/public_html/campusclub/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home3/webcapt/public_html/campusclub/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php') in /home3/webcapt/public_html/campusclub/app/Mage.php on line 37
Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home3/webcapt/public_html/campusclub/app/Mage.php on line 53
```

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127217/trying-to-install-a-magento-module-that-seems-to-not-be-compiler-compatible-ma

Answer (score 0):

To disable the compilation via code just rename the **includes** diectory from magento root folder & try to login hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Its may be the issue with cache. After renaming the cache folder also, it will show the same error. you can clear cache through index.php  of magento by

```
    $app = Mage::app();

if ($app != null)

   {  

      $cache = $app->getCache();  

      if ($cache != null)  

        {      

           $cache->clean();  

         }

   }
```

Hope it will work!